# Randomly make certain rows NA on a specific column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, random, tidyverse

I'm wondering how to randomly replace `value` on rows for which `name >= 2` with `NA` based on the following condition:

> *The higher the `name`, the larger the proportion of `NA`s by 10% increments*.

For example, if we put `NA` for **10%** of `value`s on `name==2`, then, I expect **20%** of `value`s on `name==3` to be replaced with `NA` and so on.

Is this possible in R?

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)

map_dfc(1:3, \(i) round(rbeta(5, i+.1, i+12, i*.2),2)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  mutate(name=as.numeric(str_remove(name, "...")))

"
    name value
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  0.01
 2     2  0.17
 3     3  0.31
 4     1  0.1 
 5     2  0.02
 6     3  0.17
 7     1  0.01
 8     2  0.16
 9     3  0.17
10     1  0.1 
11     2  0.27
12     3  0.22
13     1  0.24
14     2  0.08
15     3  0.06
"
```

Comment: This is very possible. One way would be to add a column with threshold values based on `name`, e.g., maybe it is `0.1` when  `name == 1`, then `0.2` when `name == 2`, etc. Then you can draw a random number for each row and compare it to the threshold. But this sounds like a homework problem... what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @GregorThomas, not a homework at all. This is for my own research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
firstprob <- 0.1
set.seed(42)
distinct(quux, name) |>
  mutate(prob = firstprob + 0.1 * (row_number() - 1)) |>
  right_join(quux, by = "name") |>
  mutate(
    value = if_else(
      name != 1 & row_number() %in% sample(n(), size = ceiling(first(prob) * n())), 
      value[NA], value), 
    .by = name)
# # A tibble: 15 × 3
#     name  prob value
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1   0.1  0.01
#  2     1   0.1  0.1 
#  3     1   0.1  0.01
#  4     1   0.1  0.1 
#  5     1   0.1  0.24
#  6     2   0.2  0.17
#  7     2   0.2  0.02
#  8     2   0.2  0.16
#  9     2   0.2  0.27
# 10     2   0.2 NA   
# 11     3   0.3 NA   
# 12     3   0.3  0.17
# 13     3   0.3  0.17
# 14     3   0.3  0.22
# 15     3   0.3 NA
```

We first reduce to the unique `name`s, assign the proportions (of `NA`) from the first through the rest, join back into the original data, then replace based on row number within the `prob` proportion of rows within each group.

This is using `.by=` so requires `dplyr_1.1.0`; replace `.by=` with the appropriate use of `group_by(.)` if older. For clarity:

```r
distinct(quux, name) |>
  mutate(prob = firstprob + 0.1 * (row_number() - 1)) |>
  right_join(quux, by = "name") |>
  group_by(name) |>
  mutate(
    value = if_else(
      name != 1 & row_number() %in% sample(n(), size = ceiling(first(prob) * n())), 
      value[NA], value), 
  ) |>
  ungroup()
```

is how you convert from the `.by=` notation in `dplyr_1.1.0` to older versions of dplyr.

Comment: Thanks, but please note that the question is asking for `NA`s to be added ONLY to `value` on rows for which `name >= 2`. Your solution adds `NA` to rows where `name >= 1` as well.

Comment: Sure, it's just a little more conditioning. See my edit.

Comment: No. The `first(.)` is because `prob` is a vector of length > 1, but the use within `sample` must be length 1. It has nothing to do with the `name>=1` thing.

Comment: I just ran it 100 times (without seeds) and got the exact same number of `NA` values every single time (0 in `name==1`, 1 in `name==2`, and 2 in `name==3`). What version of `dplyr` are you using? Look at `packageVersion("dplyr")`, and if less than 1.1.0, see the note in my answer about that.

Comment: That is why I had included the note in my answer from the start. `dplyr_1.1.0` was released 11 months ago and 1.1.4 is current. I suggest paying a little more attention to notes about package-versions in answers, especially when reading answers to questions not your own, as there are unfortunately "new features" that have been released in the last year that many answers are starting to consider safe assumptions. (Do you update your OS and/or antivirus? Similar premise: bug fixes, enhancements, and most docs/help forums will be assuming the newer versions.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option with `ave`

```
dfout <- transform(
  df,
  value = value[as.logical(
    ave(name, name, FUN = \(k) {
      l <- seq_along(k)
      n <- pmin(length(k), round(0.1 * (unique(k) - 1) * length(k)))
      ifelse(l %in% sample(l, n), NA, 1)
    })
  )]
)
```

## Verification

Given data frame `df` with `5000` rows like below

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(
  name = sample(1:5, 5000, TRUE),
  value = runif(5000)
)
```

you can see the ratio of NAs (second column of the following table)

```
> proportions(with(dfout, table(name, NAs = is.na(value))), 1)
    NAs
name     FALSE      TRUE
   1 1.0000000 0.0000000
   2 0.9000000 0.1000000
   3 0.8002081 0.1997919
   4 0.7002938 0.2997062
   5 0.6003899 0.3996101
```